# Apache mod_rewrite rewritecond -U works and then doesn't

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be easy by passing a request that doesn't match something on the current server to a proxy to see if it matches there. The rules work fine when looking for physical files and directories on the server but is doing weird things when looking for locations that exist that are not on the file system, or some kind of other routing control from php, or java or whatever. So "/redirect" doesn't exist as a file, or as a directory, then it goes to find it with -U and that also fails, good, until it hits the proxy and comes back and determines that it actually does exist on the proxy so everything is ok and then nothing actually gets proxied. Obviously I need to do something else here, but I'm stuck and the documentation and examples aren't really helping me. I might just have a case of brain fry this late in the day.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -U
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3000$1 [P,L]
```

Here is the output from the log

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /redirect
applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/redirect'
RewriteCond: input='/opt/apache/htdocs/www/redirect' pattern='-f' => not-matched
RewriteCond: input='/opt/apache/htdocs/www/redirect' pattern='-d' => not-matched
init rewrite engine with requested uri /redirect
applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/redirect'
RewriteCond: input='/opt/apache/htdocs/www/redirect' pattern='-f' => not-   matched
RewriteCond: input='/opt/apache/htdocs/www/redirect' pattern='-d' => not-   matched
RewriteCond: input='/redirect' pattern='-U' => not-matched  <-- OK GOOD
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/redirect'
rewrite '/redirect' -> 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'  <-- GOING TO LOOK
forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:3000/redirect <-- GOING TO LOOK
go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:3000/redirect [OK] <-- FOUND
RewriteCond URI (-U) check: path=/redirect -> status=200  <-- OK I GUESS I THOUGHT IT WOULD BE A REDIRECT STATUS CODE
RewriteCond: input='/redirect' pattern='-U' => matched  <-- WAIT, WHY?
pass through /redirect  <-- SIGH
```

Comment: Are you sure you want -U? This is purely to test access control of a URL path. i.e. if there are any Auth settings standing in the way of a handler for that URL. In your case, the bulk of the rewriting in your log output is from the subrequest that -U generates to test the URL. Once it gets to mod_proxy handling that sub-request with "go-ahead with proxy", control returns to the initial request with a True value (status=200) for the original -U which is why you see => matched. If you're sure you need -U, then you might be able to preclude the subrequest with `RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} !=false`

Comment: To be honest I don't know, it seemed like -U was what I needed but I'm open to any suggestions. I just need to be able to check to see if a path is available or not. These paths are not always files or directories on a server but could be controllers in various frameworks/languages that handle the requests. So short of writing something custom this was the only thing I could find that seemed to work. I like the %{IS_SUBREQ} suggestion, that seems like it would help so I will work on that and see what I can come up with.